# Value too large for defined data type in Comm command solaris

Tags: solaris, comm

When I use comm command to compare the files with 2 GB and 1.7GB I got the following error.
*Value too large for defined data type*

I tried the following command.

comm -23 file1.txt file2.txt

Solaris Generic_150401-32 i86pc

Kindly help

Comment: What does `man comm` say about files larger than 2 GB?

Comment: larger file is not supported in comm.

Comment: USAGE
     See largefile(5) for the description of the behavior of comm
     when encountering files greater than or equal to 2 Gbyte ( 2
    **31 bytes).
 Large file safe utilities
     A utility is called large file safe if  it  causes  no  data
     loss  or corruption when it encounters a large file. A util-
     ity that is large file safe is unable to process properly  a
     large file, but returns an appropriate error.

Comment: Its located under Large File safe utilities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sathiyadasan writes, Solaris 10 comm can't handle large files (>2GB).

I offer 3 options:
1) download the GNU version of comm and use that on solaris 10
2) move to Solaris 11 and use the /usr/gnu/bin/comm
3) write a more complicated script, depending on what you're trying to accomplish:

Reducing your data might make the problem more manageable. If the files have lots of duplicate entries, this workds well. If you're trying to find lines that are unique to the first file, but don't care about the order of the lines within the file, you could use:

sort -o file1.smaller -u file1.txt
sort -o file2.smaller -u file2.txt
comm -23 file1.smaller file2.smaller

Really, how you handle this depends on the nature of your data and what you're trying to discover.

Good luck!